# I've built a ascx control and I would like to be able to keep adding them using Javascript instead of having to do a full call back

Tags: asp.net, javascript, user-controls

I've built a ascx control and I would like to be able to keep adding new instances of it using JavaScript instead of having to do a AJAX callback. Is this possible? I am basically building a web form for a query control and should clause X be filled in, I want to generate a control for the next clause below. I would like to learn how to do this without doing a callback.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

ASCX are server side user controls and, to my knowledge, can only be loaded by a server event.  This can be accomplished through a full page postback or using UpdatePanels and ASP.net AJAX.

If you don't want to use these options and stick with a full JavaScript solution, you're looking at probably doing DOM manipulation and dynamically adding straight HTML.

If the ASCX controls don't change their appearance and all you're doing is showing and hiding them, one last alternative could be to load all of them into DIV tags that have their display style set to none.  Then when the user clicks on a checkbox or whatever, you can use JavaScript to show that DIV tag containing the next control.  This is how many JavaScript tab setups work.